# how can i use a shared lib in glassfish to avoid deployment of the huge libs?

Tags: deployment, jakarta-ee, glassfish, shared-libraries, shared

I have to upload about 30M for my app since it uses a lot of libraries, log, web engine and so on.

I think there should be a way to share these libs on glassfish, but I failed to figure it out. I tried to put them in domain/lib/ext but does not work.

So where should I store these libs and how should I refer to them? thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why domaindir/lib/ext does not work?

from glassfish manual:

> Optional packages are packages of Java classes and associated native code that application
>   developers can use to extend the functionality of the core platform.
>   To use the Java optional package mechanism, copy the JAR files into the domain-dir/lib/ext
>   directory, then restart the server.

Why domaindir/lib work?

> To use the Common class loader, copy the JAR files into the domain-dir/lib or as-install/lib
>   directory or copy the .class files (and other needed files, such as .properties files) into the
>   domain-dir/lib/classes directory, then restart the server.
>   Using the Common class loader makes an application or module accessible to all applications
>   or modules deployed on servers that share the same configuration.However, this accessibility
>   does not extend to application clients.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put them in `domains/domain1/lib`. But actually, I suggest to read [GlassFish equivalent to WebSphere's "shared libraries"](http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/glassfish_equivalent_to_websphere_s), **including** the [comments](http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/glassfish_equivalent_to_websphere_s#comments).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, you can also specify additional libraries in the classpath via the admin console (in Application Server > JVM settings or something like this). Then you can put them wherever you want.

(I had a quick look at Pascal's link, but I don't know if that's what they describe, if yes, my apologies for the duplicate answer.)