# Hibernate Validator @SafeHtml: org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist not found

Tags: jsoup, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a problem with the @SafeHtml annotation used in bean validation.

The annotations inside the entity:

```
@Basic
@Column(length = 100000)
@NotNull(groups = ValidationOrder1.class)
@NotBlank(groups = ValidationOrder2.class)
@Size(min = 5, max = 100000, groups = ValidationOrder3.class)
@SafeHtml(groups = ValidationOrder4.class)
private String text;
```

My dependencies inside `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

The following exception is thrown during validation:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist not found by org.glassfish.hk2.external.bean-validator
```

The full stacktrace:

```
[2014-02-07T16:27:01.786+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] [[
  Error loading class org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SafeHtmlValidator
org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SafeHtmlValidator
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:179)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createAnnotatedType(BeanManagerImpl.java:1136)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.createAnnotatedType(ForwardingBeanManager.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.DestructibleBeanInstance.createInjectionTarget(DestructibleBeanInstance.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.DestructibleBeanInstance.<init>(DestructibleBeanInstance.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.getInstance(InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.createAndInitializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForNonDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:792)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:737)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValue(ValidatorImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:983)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jsoup/safety/Whitelist;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredFieldsAction.run(GetDeclaredFieldsAction.java:30)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredFieldsAction.run(GetDeclaredFieldsAction.java:22)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:82)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:358)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:174)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist not found by org.glassfish.hk2.external.bean-validator [21]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 77 more
]]

[2014-02-07T16:27:01.788+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist not found by org.glassfish.hk2.external.bean-validator [21]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredFieldsAction.run(GetDeclaredFieldsAction.java:30)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.GetDeclaredFieldsAction.run(GetDeclaredFieldsAction.java:22)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:82)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:358)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createAnnotatedType(BeanManagerImpl.java:1136)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.createAnnotatedType(ForwardingBeanManager.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.DestructibleBeanInstance.createInjectionTarget(DestructibleBeanInstance.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.DestructibleBeanInstance.<init>(DestructibleBeanInstance.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.getInstance(InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.createAndInitializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForNonDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:792)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:737)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValue(ValidatorImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1165)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:983)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

Comment: Can you describe your deployment? It looks like you are running in the Glassfish container, which provides its own implementation of Bean Validation (as required by the EE spec). I am wondering whether there is a class loader visibility problem. JSoup is bundled within your app and I fear the Validator provided by the container cannot load this class. Maybe you can add the jar to the Glassfish installation itself?

Comment: What do yo mean with deployment and how can i add a jar to GlassFish?

Comment: With deployment, I mean what type of artifact you try to install. Is it a war or a ear or whatever. Also which exact server are you using? Type and version? That said, this might help regarding adding shared libraries to Glassfish 4 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369426/how-can-i-use-a-shared-lib-in-glassfish-to-avoid-deployment-of-the-huge-libs

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem -- Glassfish 4.1 is not loading the jsoup library even when you place the jar in as-install/lib or domain-dir/lib.

I was able to resolve the problem by placing jsoup jar on as-install/modules/endorsed