# Why does Glassfish have two 'glassfish' folders and duplicate directories?

Tags: java, glassfish

The question is in the title I guess.  Both folders have a bin directory with some duplication of scripts, etc.  Then there are multiple lib directories as well.  One in the /glassfish/lib and another in /glassfish/domains//lib.  It just seems odd to me and gets confusing as to where I should put classpath jars, direct env variables to, etc.  Is there any specific reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that it gives you the flexibility to provide libs at different visibility levels.

The folder `glassfish/lib` contains the libs which should be available for the whole server and all domains.

The folder `glassfish/domains/domain1/lib` contains only the libs which are available for `domain1`.

If you had a `domain2`, the folder `glassfish/domains/domain2/lib` would contain the libs which are required for `domain2`.

Now, as an example, if you have some libs which are required by `domain1` and `domain2`, you can put them in the folder `glassfish/lib`, so they are available for the whole server and therefore for both domains.

Another example, if you have two domains, and both domains require a different version of the same lib, you have to put the specific versions into `glassfish/domains/domain1/lib` and `glassfish/domains/domain2/lib` accordingly.

As a consequence of this, you can always put your libs into `glassfish/lib` if you only have a single domain.

**See also:**

- [GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Guider - Chapter 2 Class Loaders](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/6nmndgmhp/index.html)
- [ClassLoaders in GlassFish - a FAQ](https://blogs.oracle.com/sivakumart/entry/classloaders_in_glassfish_an_attempt)
- [How to use 3rd party libraries in glassfish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507099/how-to-use-3rd-party-libraries-in-glassfish)
- [how can i use a shared lib in glassfish to avoid deployment of the huge libs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369426/how-can-i-use-a-shared-lib-in-glassfish-to-avoid-deployment-of-the-huge-libs)